# How to create an "ATL Project" in Visual Studio Community 2015?

Tags: c++, com, visual-studio-2015, atl, shell-extensions

[This 2004 tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7484/How-to-overlay-an-icon-over-existing-shell-objects) tells me to choose `Visual C++ Project / ATL Project` in the Visual Studio new project wizard.

**PROBLEM:** The [ATL project type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd845614.aspx) does not seem to exist in my Visual Studio Community 2015.

**QUESTION:** How to make this option appear? If impossible, what is the nearest option? Tho goal is to write a shell extension in C++.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like  a full installation. http://i.stack.imgur.com/iAZRZ.png

Comment: Not sure what the status is with 2015, but in the past, ATL and MFC were not included with free Community edition, but only with paid products.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: they're included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATL project support was not installed. To fix this:

1. Click on the `Install Visual C++ 2015 Tools` seen in the screenshot above.
2. Let the download and installation happen
3. Open the `New Project` dialog again: The `New ATL Project` option should appear.

It is doable with the Community version.